# Add Google Places items into ListView

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, android-studio, google-places-api

I am implementing an application that shows the nearest restaurants. I want to have two activities, one to show the restaurants in a map, and the other one to show in a ListView.

**This is the code to retrieve the data an add markers.**

```
public class GetNearbyPlacesData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

    String googlePlacesData;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    String url;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            Log.d("GetNearbyPlacesData", "doInBackground entered");
            mMap = (GoogleMap) params[0];
            url = (String) params[1];
            DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
            googlePlacesData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
            Log.d("GooglePlaceData", googlePlacesData);
            Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "doInBackground Exit");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", e.toString());
        }
        return googlePlacesData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Entered");
        List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList = null;
        DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
        nearbyPlacesList =  dataParser.parse(result);
        Log.d("List of restaurants",nearbyPlacesList.toString());
        ShowNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Exit");
    }

    private void ShowNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nearbyPlacesList.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("onPostExecute","Entered into showing locations");
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlacesList.get(i);
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
            String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
            String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            //move map camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
        }
    }
}
```

**The code that parses the data:**

```
public class DataParser {
    public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(String jsonData) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject;

        try {
            Log.d("Places", "parse");
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Places", "parse error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return getPlaces(jsonArray);
    }

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        int placesCount = jsonArray.length();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> placeMap = null;
        Log.d("Places", "getPlaces");

        for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
            try {
                placeMap = getPlace((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
                placesList.add(placeMap);
                Log.d("Places", "Adding places");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("Places", "Error in Adding places");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return placesList;
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject googlePlaceJson) {
        HashMap<String, String> googlePlaceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String placeName = "-NA-";
        String vicinity = "-NA-";
        String latitude = "";
        String longitude = "";
        String reference = "";

        Log.d("getPlace", "Entered");

        try {
            if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("name")) {
                placeName = googlePlaceJson.getString("name");
            }
            if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("vicinity")) {
                vicinity = googlePlaceJson.getString("vicinity");
            }
            latitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
            longitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
            reference = googlePlaceJson.getString("reference");
            googlePlaceMap.put("place_name", placeName);
            googlePlaceMap.put("vicinity", vicinity);
            googlePlaceMap.put("lat", latitude);
            googlePlaceMap.put("lng", longitude);
            googlePlaceMap.put("reference", reference);
            Log.d("getPlace", "Putting Places");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("getPlace", "Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return googlePlaceMap;
    }
}
```

**This is for the HTTPConnection:**

```
public class DownloadUrl {

    public String readUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();
            Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

**This is what I have tried to do to retrieve the response:**

```
public class ListRestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new GetNearbyPlacesData().execute();
    }


}
```

**EDIT**

**Added activity that retrieves my latitude and longitude and constructs my url:**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
double latitude;
double longitude;
private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 10000;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    //Check if Google Play Services Available or not
    if (!CheckGooglePlayServices()) {
        Log.d("onCreate", "Finishing test case since Google Play Services are not available");
        finish();
    }
    else {
        Log.d("onCreate","Google Play Services available.");
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

private boolean CheckGooglePlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                    0).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


        String Restaurant = "restaurant";

            mMap.clear();
            String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Restaurant);
            Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
            DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
            DataTransfer[1] = url;
            GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
            getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nearby Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace) {

    //Place current location marker
    latitude = 45.772;
    longitude = 21.219;

    StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + nearbyPlace);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "-");
    Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("onLocationChanged", "entered");

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Your Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.format("latitude:%.3f longitude:%.3f",latitude,longitude));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Removing Location Updates");
    }
    Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}
```

}

**Logcat:**

```
1-16 16:18:12.101 4224-4224/com.upt.cti.nearbyrestaurant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                                                                                at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                                                                                at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
                                                                                at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
                                                                                at com.upt.cti.nearbyrestaurant.DataParser.parse(DataParser.java:25)
                                                                                at com.upt.cti.nearbyrestaurant.GetNearbyPlacesData.onPostExecute(GetNearbyPlacesData.java:46)
                                                                                at com.upt.cti.nearbyrestaurant.GetNearbyPlacesData.onPostExecute(GetNearbyPlacesData.java:19)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I get a NullpointerException. Is this not enough ? Could somebody help me ?

Comment: We need the entire logcat message. Please post here, otherwise it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: @AndreiT: I added the LogCat

Comment: Try to debug the app and check if the results json is a valid json file because it seems the parsing fails.

Answer (score 0):

I used great tutorial from Androidhive, [link here.](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) Did you check, do you get something in onPostExecute as a result ? Where it become null, on parsing or on retrieving?

Comment: Do I have to get my current location(latitude and longitude) and make the url call again ?

Answer (score 0):

Maps Activity.java

```
package com.android.trainee.activity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.trainee.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
private final int[] MAP_TYPES = {GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE,
        GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL,
        GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID,
        GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN,
        GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE};
private int curMapTypeIndex = 1;
int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 100;
Marker currLocationMarker;
MarkerOptions markerOptions;
String result;
View mapView;
ListView simpleList;
ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready 
 to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
 getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapView = mapFragment.getView();
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    simpleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);


}

private void gps() {
    if (googleApiClient == null) {
        googleApiClient = new 
GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
        location();
    }
}

private void location() {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(100);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new 
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(false); // this is the key ingredient
    PendingResult result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.
            checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Result result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MapsActivity.this, 
REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    }
                    break;
                case 
LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS enabled", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            location();
        }

    }
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the 
camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be 
prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once 
the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    gps();
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPES[curMapTypeIndex]);
    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            //     mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new 
GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    //save current location
                    getAddress(latLng);
                    location(latLng);
                }
            });
            if (mapView != null &&
                    mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null) {
                // Get the button view
                View locationButton = ((View) 
mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1"))
                        .getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
                // and next place it, on bottom right (as Google Maps app)
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                        locationButton.getLayoutParams();
                // position on right bottom
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 
RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
            }

            mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new 
GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(final CameraPosition 
cameraPosition) {
                    mGoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new 
GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapLoaded() {
                            LatLng latLng = 
mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                            getAddress(latLng);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            gps();
        }
    } else {
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener()  
{
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                //save current location
                getAddress(latLng);
                location(latLng);
            }
        });
        if (mapView != null &&
                mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null) {
            // Get the button view
            View locationButton = ((View) 
mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1"))
                    .getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            // and next place it, on bottom right (as Google Maps app)
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                    locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            // position on right bottom
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 
RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
        }

        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new 
GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(final CameraPosition cameraPosition) 
{
                mGoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new 
GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapLoaded() {
                        LatLng latLng = 
mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                        getAddress(latLng);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}

public void location(LatLng latLng) {
    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title(result);

markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker));
    currLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}

public List<Address> getAddress(LatLng latLng) {
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        if (latLng.latitude != 0 || latLng.longitude != 0) {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude,
                    latLng.longitude, 1);
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
            Toast.makeText(this, address + " - " + city + " - " + country,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            aa.add(address + city + country);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this, R.layout.activity_listview, R.id.textView, aa);
            simpleList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            return addresses;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "latitude and longitude are null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    //     gpsTreker();
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);

 mLocationRequest.setPriority
(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, 
mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), 
location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");

 markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker
(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12));
}

}


activity_maps.xml
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        tools:context="com.android.trainee.activity.MapsActivity">
</fragment>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/simpleListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:divider="#cfc4c4"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

activity_listview. xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDarktab" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

android manifast.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.trainee">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" 
/> -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.HomeSplashActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.SignUpActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.LoginActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.DashBoard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dash_board"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.ProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.Contects" />
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string 
resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign 
the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the 
release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in 
src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MapsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.BackgroundServices"></activity>

    <service android:name=".services.MediaService" />

</application>

</manifest>``
```